# how to add years in date in angular js in the html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code on my html

```
<p>Date issued: <span class="b">{{orderPrint.orderDetails.received_date | date : "medium"}}</span></p>
```

It displays something like this:
Date: Mar 16, 2018 7:39:08 PM

I want to display Date: Mar 16, 2023 7:39:08 PM. how can I do that?

Comment: Please post code that you have tried.

Comment: any reason or logic to show 2023 there?

Answer (score 2):

> We can do this using setYear() in Date.

For eg.

```
var myDate = new Date();
```

and +1 to add a year in current date.

```
myDate.setYear(userdob.getFullYear() + 1);
```

In your case, just update your date value as below.

```
var updatedYear = orderPrint.orderDetails.received_date.getFullYear() + 5;
orderPrint.orderDetails.received_date.setYear(updatedYear);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage In HTML Template Binding:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

Example:

```
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span>:
<span>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>:
<span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span>:
<span>{{'1288323623006' | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</span><br>
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span>:
<span>{{'1288323623006' | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</span><br>
```

For more details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add timezone then use this

new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"})

if you want to just add year/month/time in date.
then follow this steps

step 1- first need to parse date. use

var a = data.parse(new date());

step 2 - a = a + (365*24*60*60*1000)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add year follow this javascript

```
   var dat=new Date();
    var y=dat.getFullYear()+5;
    dat.setFullYear(y);
```

and amol bhor also fine.